# Python read() function doesn't return anything

Tags: python

So my intention is to record all keypresses of my keyboard and store those keypresses in a notepad
so i can replay them from that save file but even when  `wf.write()` overwrites the file with the
keypresses the  `print(data)` doesnt print anything, also `keyboard.play()` can't play and string type variable but that's something i am still working on, by now i just want to see the read result.

```
import keyboard
import time
import random
import os

with open("pasos.txt",'r') as rf:
    with open("pasos.txt",'w') as wf:
        lc=keyboard.record(until="shift")
        sc=str(lc)
        wf.write(sc)
        data=rf.read()
        print(data)
        #keyboard.play(save,speed_factor=1)
``
```

Comment: Why do you need to read what you just wrote? Just use the variable `sc`

Comment: I just wanted to make sure it is getting save in the file. @Barmar

Comment: I will use 'rf.read()' in another py file to only read the saved keypresses . @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File output is buffered. You need to flush the output to the file so that it can be read by another stream.

```
with open("pasos.txt",'r') as rf:
    with open("pasos.txt",'w') as wf:
        lc=keyboard.record(until="shift")
        sc=str(lc)
        wf.write(sc)
        wr.flush()
        data=rf.read()
        print(data)
        #keyboard.play(save,speed_factor=1)
```